# Sum/Count Formulas auto adjust for inserted rows

Tags: excel

Looking to create a sum and a count formula that will automatically adjust itself for new rows that are inserted within the range.

For example if I have the formula in cell D55 `=SUM(D17:D54)`. Every time I insert a new row within that range, I need to change the top range of my formula to account for it.

Is there a way to write a formula that will automatically adjust itself, so that every time I add a new row I will not need to change my summation formula?

Comment: it's already automatically adjustes: if you insert new row between `17` and `54`, your formula (in cell `D56`) would become `=SUM(D17:D55)`

Comment: @pnuts, OP said `I have the formula in cell D55`, wouldn't your formula `=Sum(D17:D55)` create circular reference?

Answer (score 9):

Try

```
D55: =SUM(INDIRECT("D17:D"&ROW()-1))
```

This should dynamically adjust to added rows since when adding rows at row 17 the current value at `D17` shifts to `D18` and no value is present at `D17`. `INDIRECT()` should take this into account. `ROW()-1` ensures that even when rows are added immediately preceding the formula these are still taken into account.

Edit: I should have added that this can be applied to any formula. Simply replace the range part of your formula with the `INDIRECT`.
And a quick explanation: the `INDIRECT` creates an Excel reference from a string so you can construct your formula using dynamic objects. The `ROW` part of the formula acts as the dynamic factor which is completely dependent on the row count that you add but is independent of the position at which you add your new row.

Comment: This works well, tested in Excel 97 and 2000. For anyone using this formula, adapt the `"D17:D"` reference to your own starting cell and column (eg. `"G3:G"`). Also, say you left a blank row between the bottom of the data you are summing and the formula, then replace `-1` with `-2`. Good answer.

Comment: Thanks Alain, glad you liked my suggested solution!

Answer (score 1):

I think people are misunderstanding.  You're inserting a row at the TOP of your range correct?

If so, I would suggest formatting the range as a table.  That way your table could look like this:

[image]

And the sum function would be simply:

```
=SUM([Data])
```

when a row is inserted above the 7, everything is automatically updated.

[image]

Comment: Do you happen to know in what version of Excel the feature =SUM([ColumnHeader]) was added? This doesn't work in Excel 97 or 2000. This also doesn't appear to answer the question because the OPs question started from row 17 (not row 2).

Answer (score 1):

One of the best option would be to use Offset with starting cell.
=SUM(A1:offset(currentcell,-1,0,1,1))
currentcell => cell in which sum is required
This will sum from A1 (this can be the top row from where summation is required) till the immediate row above the sum function.

Comment: Surround inline code with backticks. Looks nicer and is easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at this [excellent link that talks about using tables to hold your ranges](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/using-formulas-in-excel-tables-HA102749547.aspx). This would be my recommendation ... wrap your data in a table. This will create a structured yet flexible reference.

As is noted here, and also from experience, "Because table data ranges often change, the cell references for structured references adjust automatically. For example, if you use a table name in a formula to count all the data cells in a table, and you then add a row of data, the cell reference automatically adjusts."